# Distribution of Brownian motion at Exponential time

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

I'm trying to determine a probablity of the form
$$
\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a),
$$

where W is a brownian motion with drift d, and parameter $\sigma^2$ and independent of $Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$. By using the reflection principle for Wiener processes, I believe I may rewrite the above as
$$
2\mathbb{P}(W_{Y_n}>a).
$$

However, at this point I don't know how to move further, since I'm unsure of the distribution of $W_{Y_n}$. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a) &= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_{\{\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a\}})  \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_{\{\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a\}}|Y))  \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a|Y))  \\
&= \int_{y\in \Bbb R^+}\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a|Y=y)d\mathbb{P}(Y\le y) \\
&= \int_{y\in \Bbb R^+}\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy \tag{1} \\
\end{align}
$$
As $Y$ and $W_t$ are independent, we can write
$$\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t|\{ Y=y\} =\sup_{0 \leq t \leq y} W_t  \tag{2}$$
**Remark**: the independency here plays a very important role because if not, we need to rewrite $(2)$ as
$$\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t|\{ Y=y\} =\sup_{0 \leq t \leq y} (W_t|\{Y = y \})  $$
and then determine the marginal distribution  $W_t|\{Y = y \}$ which is usually not easy.

Return back to $(2)$, we have $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq y} W_t $ is equal in distribution to $|W_y|$ and so
$$\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a|Y=y) = 2\mathbb{P}(W_y>a) =2 \Phi\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{y}}\right) \qquad ,a>0$$
with $\Phi(.)$ the cumulative probability function of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

From $(1)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0 \leq t \leq Y} W_t > a) &=2\lambda \int_0^{+\infty}\Phi\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{y}}\right)e^{-\lambda y}dy \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Q.E.D

Comment: Generally I understand your process very well, thanks a lot! I am however wondering about two things;
1. Why are we integrating with respect to $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)$ in (1)? Is this just some definition, I'm forgetting about?

2. How come the last factor in (3) is $ye^{-\lambda y}$? If the term is the cdf of Y, shouldn't it be $1-e^{-\lambda y}$? Or if it was the pdf, $\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$.

Thanks a lot, i'll definitely accept yours as the solution when I've got those two cleared!

Comment: @NaveedNeghabat 1/ perhaps you familialize more with $f_Y(y)$ ($f_Y$ is the density function of $Y$) than $dP(Y\le y) = f_Y(y)dy$), they are just two ways of writing the integral. I change the answer. 2/ It's a typo, I changed it.

Comment: Ah, that makes great sense! Thank you so much, I really appreciate the quick response!

Comment: @NaveedNeghabat You're welcome!

Comment: Hope it's alright if I follow up on one more thing I am a bit unsure of.
You write $\mathbb{P}(W_y > a) = \Phi(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{y}})$, where $\Phi$ is the cdf of $N(0,1)$. How come this is true? I thought by definition, $W_y \sim N(d y, \sigma^2 y)$. Would the equality not require $d = 0$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$?

Comment: Working on it a bit more, I've written it out like this
$$
\mathbb{P}(W_y > a) = \mathbb{P})(\frac{W_y - dy}{\sigma\sqrt{y}} > \frac{a - dy}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}) = \Phi(-\frac{a-dy}{\sigma\sqrt{y}}).
$$

Would this not be correct, since $\frac{W_y - dy}{\sigma\sqrt{y}} \sim N(0,1)$ for all values of $d$ and $\sigma \neq 0$, when $W_y \sim N(dy,\sigma^2 y)$?

Comment: @NaveedNeghabat you have
$$\mathbb{P}(W_y >a) = \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{y}\mathcal{N}(0,1) >a) =  \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{N}(0,1) >\frac{a}{\sqrt{y}})=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{N}(0,1) <-\frac{a}{\sqrt{y}})=\Phi(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{y}})$$

Comment: But if $W_y \sim N(dy,\sigma^2 y)$ (that's at least the definition of the Brownian motion, I've learnt), that would not make $\frac{W_y}{\sqrt{y}} \sim N(0,1)$ without further assuming d = 0 and $\sigma = 1$. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @NaveedNeghabat No, from the definition of BM, you have $W_t = \sqrt{t}\mathcal{N}(0,1)=\mathcal{N}(0,t)$ in law.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126411/discussion-between-naveed-neghabat-and-nn2).